# Is there a way to connect filter box under 2 tabs in superset?

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

I used Apache superset to design the dashboard. I divide the dashboard into 2 tabs called, "sales" and “details” as you can see in the screenshot. I have included 5 filters in both tabs called "date”, “brand”, “kitchen”, “channel” and “country".

I used the same view for both of the tabs under “sales” and “details”.  when I change values on any filter box, the charts have to be updated on both tabs. Not just one tab.

Is there a way to connect that 5-filter box under every 2 tabs?

[image: sales dashboard view]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the filter for one tab should work and pre-applied for another tab within the same dashboard, you can check whether the filter columns are in the tab where the filters are not working. Also, filter box is replaced by proper filters in superset 1.4 which u can see and create in right nav bar